# Отображения расписания занятий с возможностью синхронизации с сервером

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые) 
Есть идея создать приложение (android) для отображения расписания занятий с возможностью синхронизации с сервером. Расписание храниться в XML-файле. Суть вопроса такова есть парсер, работает вроде бы правильно, но в идеале он в цикле получает данные и в нем же отображает. Не могу придумать что-либо адекватное для того чтоб запихнуть данные в TextView в активности (активность показывает только один день недели и переключается).
Вот код парсера:

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(1);

    /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
    TextView Item[];
    TextView ItemNumber[];

    try {

        URL url = new URL(
                "http://timetable.esy.es/Timetable.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("day");
        //doc.getElementById("Понедельник");
        //NodeList nodeList11 = (NodeList) doc.getElementById("Превая");
        NodeList nodeList11 = doc.getElementsByTagName("subj");

        /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
        Item = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        ItemNumber = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

        String str = Integer.toString(nodeList11.getLength());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, str);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList11.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            Item[i] = new TextView(this);
            ItemNumber[i] = new TextView(this);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList ItemList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("subj");
            Element ItemElement = (Element) ItemList.item(0);
            ItemList = ItemElement.getChildNodes();
            Item[i].setText("Subject = "
                + ((Node) ItemList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
            ItemNumber[i].setText("Teacher= "
                + ItemElement.getAttribute("tech"));

            layout.addView(Item[i]);
            layout.addView(ItemNumber[i]);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

    /** Set the layout view to display */
    setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: Объясните толком в чем проблема, как нужно показывать данные, почему не получается парсить? Из вашего вопроса не понятно ничего!

Comment: Суть в том. Что нужно придумать обработчик который после получения данных с парсера будет заносить их в мои textview активности для отображения.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы создал следующие модели

```
public class Week{
    String name;
    ArrayList<Day> days;
}

public class Day{
    ArrayList<Subj> subjs;
}

public class Subj{
    String name;
    String aud;
    String tech;
}
```

В парсере заполнял бы их, [parcelable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) передавал в активити! 
На активити один день, говорите? Передавал бы на эту активити нужный Day, пихал бы в адаптер списка массив ArrayList<Subj> subjs получился бы список с лентами!